# Custom ListView with Filter on textChanged

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter, custom-lists, android-filter

I found many questions and answers related to my problem. But I am unable to achieve with those. I have a ListView, in which all the datas from DB is displayed. Now I have to filter from that list, when I type letters on editext. The filter I tried was always showing error in Filter and FilterResult class. I am trying to find solution from yesterday. I know, I am doing something somewhere wrong, but I am unable to find what is that and where. How to fix this filter in my code.

Display All Data from DB:

```
private void getAdapterView() {
    List<NewCustomerGetSetter> cont = ncdbh.getAllCustomerBikeWithStatusOfP(); // Get all the value from DB
    for (NewCustomerGetSetter cn : cont) {
        cust_name.add(cn.getName()); //Below all are List
        cust_mobile.add(cn.getMobile1());
        vehicle_number.add(cn.getBikeNo());  
        from_date.add(cn.getFromDate());
        to_date.add(cn.getToDate());
        days.add(cn.getTotalDays());
        amount.add(cn.getTotalCost());

        Log.d(cn.getID()+"",cn.getName()+" "+cn.getMobile1()+" "+count);
        count++;
    }
    // Pass values to custom Adapter
    list_return.setAdapter(new ReturnVehicleCustomAdapter(this, cust_name, cust_mobile, vehicle_number,from_date,to_date,days,amount));     
}
```

AfterTextChanged Function

```
search.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
        //Not coded. Depends on Shorted filter problem Solved need to think how to pass/ call that filter.
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
    }
});
```

Custom Adapter Class:

```
public class ReturnVehicleCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter{ 
    private Filter mFilter;
    //ReturnVehicle rv = new ReturnVehicle();
    List<String> cust_mobile = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> vehicle_number = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> cust_name = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> cust_from = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> cust_to = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> cust_days = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> cust_amount = new ArrayList<String>();
    Context context, context1;

    private LayoutInflater inflater = null;

    public ReturnVehicleCustomAdapter(ReturnVehicle vehicleMasterClass, List<String> cust_name_,
            List<String> cust_mobile_, List<String> vehicle_number_,List<String> cust_from_,
            List<String> cust_to_, List<String> cust_days_,List<String> vehicle_amount_) {
        cust_name=cust_name_;
        cust_mobile=cust_mobile_;
        vehicle_number=vehicle_number_;
        cust_to=cust_to_;
        cust_from=cust_from_;
        cust_days=cust_days_;
        cust_amount=vehicle_amount_;
        context=vehicleMasterClass;
        inflater = ( LayoutInflater )context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    public ReturnVehicleCustomAdapter(ReturnVehicle returnVehicle) {
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return cust_mobile.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    public class Holder1 {
        TextView tv;
        TextView tv1;
        TextView tv2;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        final Object[] cust_mobile_obj = cust_mobile.toArray();
        final Object[] vehicle_number_obj = vehicle_number.toArray();
        final Object[] cust_name_obj = cust_name.toArray();
        final Object[] cust_from_obj = cust_from.toArray();
        final Object[] cust_to_obj = cust_to.toArray();
        final Object[] cust_days_obj = cust_days.toArray();
        final Object[] cust_amount_obj = cust_amount.toArray();
        Holder1 holder1 = new Holder1();
        View rowView1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.return_custom_listview, null);
        holder1.tv = (TextView) rowView1.findViewById(R.id.r_name);
        holder1.tv1 = (TextView) rowView1.findViewById(R.id.r_mobile);
        holder1.tv2 = (TextView) rowView1.findViewById(R.id.r_bike);
        cust_mobile.toString();
        holder1.tv.setText((CharSequence) vehicle_number_obj[position]);
        holder1.tv1.setText((CharSequence) cust_name_obj[position]);
        holder1.tv2.setText((CharSequence) cust_mobile_obj[position]);

        rowView1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {            
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ((ReturnVehicle) context).name_ = cust_name_obj[position].toString();
                ((ReturnVehicle) context).mobile_ = cust_mobile_obj[position].toString();
                ((ReturnVehicle) context).bike1 = vehicle_number_obj[position].toString();
                ((ReturnVehicle) context).from_date1 = cust_from_obj[position].toString();
                ((ReturnVehicle) context).to_date1 = cust_to_obj[position].toString();
                ((ReturnVehicle) context).days1 = cust_days_obj[position].toString();
                ((ReturnVehicle) context).amount1 = cust_amount_obj[position].toString();
                ((ReturnVehicle) context).name.setText(((ReturnVehicle)context).name_);
                ((ReturnVehicle) context).mobile.setText(((ReturnVehicle)context).mobile_);
                ((ReturnVehicle) context).bike.setText(((ReturnVehicle)context).bike1);
                ((ReturnVehicle) context).from.setText(((ReturnVehicle)context).from_date1);
                ((ReturnVehicle) context).eto.setText(((ReturnVehicle)context).to_date1);
                ((ReturnVehicle) context).tdays.setText(((ReturnVehicle)context).days1);
                ((ReturnVehicle) context).price.setText(((ReturnVehicle)context).amount1);
                ((ReturnVehicle) context).extend.setText(((ReturnVehicle)context).df.format(((ReturnVehicle) context).c.getTime()).toString());
                ((ReturnVehicle)context).diffDateSet();
                //Toast.makeText(context, "You Clicked "+cust_mobile_obj[position], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });   
        return rowView1;
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return new Filter() {
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                Log.d("", "**** PUBLISHING RESULTS for: " + constraint);
                vehicle_number = (List<String>) results.values;
                ReturnVehicleCustomAdapter.this.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                Log.d("", "**** PERFORM FILTERING for: " + constraint);
                List<String> filteredResults = getFilteredResults(constraint);

                FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
                results.values = filteredResults;

                return results;
            }

            private List<String> getFilteredResults(CharSequence constraint) {
                if (constraint.length() == 0) {
                    return  vehicle_number;
                }
                List<String> listResult = new ArrayList<String>();
                for (String obj : vehicle_number){
                   // if (condition){
                        listResult.add(obj);
                  //  }
                }
                return listResult;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: what is `ncdbh`? where do you get data from?

Comment: ncdbh is the object for a class which contains the function getAllCustomerBikeWithStatusOfP() to get all the Bikes from Sqlite DB

Comment: so use a `SimpleCursorAdapter` with setup `FilterQueryProvider`

Comment: Thank you @pskink. Can you please provide a simple code or link, to find the implementation of SimpleCursorAdapter with setup FilterQueryProvider

Comment: just google for `SimpleCursorAdapter`, skip google and stackoverflow sites

Comment: @pskink, Why it is not possible with Filter method I am using. If it is possible, say what I am doing wrong pls.

Comment: it is possible but why to make your life harder if you may do filtering in easy way like [this](http://pastebin.com/8zYLg5eg) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I felt SimpleCursorAdapter was difficult to implement. So I found solution for the filtering by Filter Methods. Below is the code.

```
  @Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    if(valueFilter==null) {
        valueFilter=new ValueFilter();
    }
    return valueFilter;
}
/**This class do all the filters*/
private class ValueFilter extends Filter {
    /**Invoked in a worker thread to filter the data according to the constraint.*/
    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
        FilterResults results=new FilterResults();
        if(constraint!=null && constraint.length()>0){
            ArrayList<ReturnVehicleListValueGetSet> filterList=new ArrayList<ReturnVehicleListValueGetSet>();
            for(int i=0;i<filter_list.size();i++){
                if((filter_list.get(i).getName().toUpperCase()).contains(constraint.toString().toUpperCase())) {
                    ReturnVehicleListValueGetSet contacts = new ReturnVehicleListValueGetSet();
                    contacts.setName(filter_list.get(i).getName());
                    contacts.setMob(filter_list.get(i).getMob());
                    contacts.setVehNum(filter_list.get(i).getVehNum());
                    filterList.add(contacts);
                }
            }
            results.count=filterList.size();
            results.values=filterList;
        }else{
            results.count=filter_list.size();
            results.values=filter_list;
        }
        return results;
    }

    /**Invoked in the UI thread to publish the filtering results in the user interface.*/
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,FilterResults results) {
        veh_list=(ArrayList<ReturnVehicleListValueGetSet>) results.values;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: Most of your questions answered by yourself great. . .